# navit language on Raspberry pi3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, navit

I follow the tutorial of this page http://ozzmaker.com/navigating-navit-raspberry-pi/

everything seems fine. I downloaded Asia -Korea, Japan

and I also changed the language as "ko_KR" but the problem is happened blow picture.[image]

the letters don't come out. Is there any solution?

Comment: I have flagged your question as not being programming related, but rather a general computing question. You will have better luck asking on SuperUser or a relevant RPi forum. However, to give you a hint, could it be that either the font you are using or the locale you are using doesn't support the characters you are trying to display.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Ah sorry. Thank you for let me know. But, there is a official document and it says it supports my characters. I have to figure out. Thank you!